# Update or Insert object list into mongodb array in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to upsert array elements for a single document.

I want to provide list of objects to mongo query, and for each object if exists (based on some field) in an mongo document **array**, replace the object in the array, if not exists, add it to the array.

I know this can be done using application side, but can this be done using 1 transactional query?

example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b429ba0e27b508d854483e"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "letter" : "a"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "letter" : "b"
        },
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "letter" : "c"
        }
    ],
    "tester" : "tom"
}
```

Now, I want to pass to pass to my query the following objects:

```
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "letter" : "c-new"
            "newField": "some string"
        },
        {
            "id" : "4",
            "letter" : "D"
        }
```

Based on *id* field I want mongo to see that:

1. id:3 already exists, so it will replace the current element with the new object provided
2. id:4 doesn't exists, so it will add it to the array elements.

(that's basically called upsert).

Comment: @Minsky this is not trivial, and might be impossiable for mongodb to run in 1 query. Mongodb has upsert for a whole document, but what I need is upserting for an array elelment. not only that, I want to run it for multiple object in 1 query. you can have mongo document which has array with some objects in it, and I need to replace if exists, or add if not exists, for each of the provided query elelments

Comment: @Minsky I edited my question, example provided

Comment: Probably not possible.  Maybe someone else knows.